# Unable to connect to internet with Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Tags: 12.04, virtualbox, internet

I wanted to try Ubuntu, but Wubi refused to work with me, so I got a pre-created ubuntu VM, and used VirtualBox to use it. Ubuntu had a great interface, and I liked it, but it refused to connect to the internet. I tried searching through Ask Ubuntu and other sites, but found no help. If someone could help me out, it would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change following settings on your vmware.. See the image below. To access the settings, select the virtual machine. Before you click " Play virtual machine", click the option " Edit Virtual Machine settings" below it.

Select following settings:

Click on " Network Adapter" and

- Under Device Status > select connect at power on
- Under Network Connection: Select>  NAT: Used to share the host....."

save the settings and start the virtual machine.

Hopefully that solves your problem, reply if you still have issues.

Comment: I appreciate your response, but is there a way to do something like that, but with VirtualBox?